# How to implement a server "callback" on gRPC

Tags: .net, grpc, protobuf-net

I make a POC on gRPC to see what its possible to do and migrate a WCF application on .Net 5

POC is a simple chat, send new message and all clients get message

Shared code

```
public interface IChatService
{
    IAsyncEnumerable<MessageResponse> Subscribe();
    ValueTask PostMessage(MessageRequest msg);
}

[ProtoContract]
public class MessageRequest
{
    public MessageRequest(string user, string msg)
    {
        User = user;
        Msg = msg;
    }

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Msg { get; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string User { get; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class MessageResponse
{
    public MessageResponse(string user, string msg)
    {
        User = user;
        Msg = msg;
        Date = DateTime.Now;
    }

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Msg { get; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string User { get; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public DateTime Date { get; }
}
```

Client-side code :

```
        using var http = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://localhost:10042");

        var chatService = http.CreateGrpcService<IChatService>();

        await foreach (var msg in chatService.Subscribe())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{msg.Date} : {msg.User} - {msg.Msg}");
        }

        await chatService.PostMessage(new MessageRequest("User1", "MyMessage"));
```

Server-side Code :

```
public class ChatService : IChatService
{
    private static readonly List<MessageResponse> OldMessages = new List<MessageResponse>();

    public async IAsyncEnumerable<MessageResponse> Subscribe()
    {
        foreach (var msg in OldMessages)
        {
            await Task.Delay(10);
            yield return msg;
        }
    }

    public async ValueTask PostMessage(MessageRequest msg)
    {
        await Task.Delay(10);
        OldMessages.Add(new MessageResponse(msg.User, msg.Msg));
    }
}
```

In the idea, Subscribe method send to client when a new message is post
and PostMessage method add a message to the chat (obvious)

But i don't understand how on server-side code i can "add" message to the IAsyncEnumerable return by Subscribe ?
With proto, it will be someyhing like that :

```
service ChatService {
  rpc Subscribe (request) returns (stream response);
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are using a simple `foreach` loop over a list. If you `.Add` to this list, the `foreach` will break, and no more data will be returned. What you essentially need is a thread-safe async-enabled queue mechanism that is *designed* for a producer/consumer scenario. Fortunately, [`Channel<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-1?view=net-5.0) offers such a mechanism. You would, however, still need to push data into all of the subscriber instances, which is probably the bigger challenge - it usually isn't the case that you want to notify the same instance that is calling `.Add`